# getting null value after passing a parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out why the value of `FinalTransactionSortableField.fromCode(orderBy)` is coming out to be null.I am using a REST client with which
the parameters are getting passed into the following controller method.

I have the following method in my controller class :

```
public ResponseEntity<SetRESTData<FinancialTransactionDTO>> getTFIUse(

    @RequestParam(value = "bId", required = true) final String bId,
    @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) final String statusString,
    @RequestParam(value = "transactionMethod", required = false) final String transactionMethodString,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) final String orderBy,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false) final String sortDirectionString) {

    //line 76 below 
    final FinancialTransactionPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
      null : new FinancialTransactionPaginationData(FinancialTransactionSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);
    //line# 79 below  
    final ServiceResultDetails<Set<FinancialTransactionDTO>> resultsDetails =
      financialTransactionService.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(businessId,status, method, paginationData);

  }
```

When I put a break point on line #79, I can see that the pagination data is returning null for `field` as shown in the screenshot below from the debugger in eclipse:

[image]

```
The FinalTransactionSortableField class has`fromCode()` method defined as follows :

 public static FinancialTransactionSortableField fromCode(final String code) {       
   // Line #61 below
    return CODE_MAP.get(code);
  }
```

When I put the debug point at line #61(return statement), I can see the value `createdTs` on the debugger in eclipse as follows :

[image]

For Reference :

1) `CODE_MAP` is a Map defined in the class FinancialTransactionSortableField as follows :

```
public enum FinancialTransactionSortableField implements MappableEnum<FinancialTransactionSortableField>, SortableField {

  ID(DefaultSortableField.ID.getCode(), "Transaction Id", DefaultSortableField.ID.getColumnName()),
  CASH_AMOUNT("CashAmount", "Cash Amount", "cashAmount"),
  SECURITY_AMOUNT("SecurityAmount", "Security Amount", "securityAmount"),
  STATUS("Status", "Status", "status"),
  CREATED_TS(DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getCode(),
             DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getDescription(),
             DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getColumnName()),;

  private final String code;
  private final String description;
  private final String columnName;

  private static final Map<String, FinancialTransactionSortableField> CODE_MAP =
    MappableEnumUtil.buildCodeMap(FinancialTransactionSortableField.class);

  private FinancialTransactionSortableField(final String code, final String description, final String columnName) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.columnName = columnName;
  }

  @JsonValue
  @Override
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public String getColumnName() {
    return columnName;
  }

  @Override
  public FinancialTransactionSortableField toEnum(final String code) {
    return fromCode(code);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static FinancialTransactionSortableField fromCode(final String code) {
    return CODE_MAP.get(code);
  }

}
```

2) The implementation of `buildCodeMap` method is as follows:

```
 public static <E extends Enum<E> & MappableEnum<E>> Map<String, E> buildCodeMap(final Class<E> enumClass) {
    return buildLookupMap(enumClass,
                          new EnumValueGetter<E>() {
                            @Override
                            public Set<String> getKeys(final E e) {
                              final Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(1);
                              set.add(e.getCode());
                              return set;
                            }
                          });
  }
```

3) Here is `buildLookupMap` implementation

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & MappableEnum<E>> Map<String, E> buildLookupMap(
    final Class<E> enumClass, final EnumValueGetter<E> getter) {
    final Set<E> values = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass);
    final E enumValue = values.iterator().next();
    addToExampleMap(enumClass, enumValue);

    final Map<String, E> lookupMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(values.size());


    for (final E value : values) {
      final Set<String> keys = getter.getKeys(value);
      for (final String key : keys) {
        if (lookupMap.containsKey(key)) {
          throw new FPIllegalArgumentException("Lookup map for {} has duplicate key {}", enumClass.getSimpleName(), key);
        } else {
          lookupMap.put(key, value);
        }
      }
    }

    return lookupMap;
  }
```

4) Implementation of `addToExampleMap`method and `EnumValueGetter` interface is as follows which is used above:

```
 private static synchronized <E extends Enum<E> & MappableEnum<E>> void addToExampleMap(
    final Class<E> enumClass, final E enumValue) {
    if (!EXAMPLE_MAP.containsKey(enumClass)) {
      EXAMPLE_MAP.put(enumClass, enumValue);
    }
  } 

public static interface EnumValueGetter<E extends Enum<E> & MappableEnum<E>> {
    Set<String> getKeys(E e);
  }
```

and `EXAMPLE_MAP` is a map which is declared in the class at the start like this :

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, MappableEnum<?>> EXAMPLE_MAP =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, MappableEnum<?>>(1000);
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Well, if the value of `orderBy` doesn't exists in `CODE_MAP` the get method of the map will return null.

Comment: @Evgeni But then, shouldn't the line `return CODE_MAP.get(code);` be returning null in that case as well or am I interpreting something wrong here?

Comment: yes, it would be null. It has a key but has null value

Comment: @janek Would you like me to paste the code of `FinancialTransactionPaginationData` and ` FinancialTransactionSortableField` for your reference?

Comment: @janek I updated the code in #3, #4, #5 under reference section. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @janek You mean I should put a break point on the line where `CREATED_TS` enum is declared in `FinancialTransactionSortableField` class?

Comment: get FinancialTransactionSortableField.values() somewhere on the execution path in your code and place breakepoint after that instruction, and inspect all the values (or print them, whatever)

Comment: Your question can be entirely reduced to the implementation of `buildCodeMap`. As presented, this is not a Spring, Spring-4, or Hibernate problem. Please remove those tags. Remove the source code for `LinkedHashMap`. Remove `PaginationData` and `FinancialTransactionPaginationData`. Leave only your invocation of `fromCode` with evidence of a non-null argument value, the implementation of your `enum`. And add the implementation of `buildCodeMap`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Done. Please take a look.

Comment: Hi guys, I found the problem. While making an API call using REST client, I was using lowercase `c` in the URL as shown here: `http://localhost.com:8080/int/fin/trs?bId=B-XYZ&sortBy=createdTs`, however it should be `CreatedTs` because the `DefaultSortableField` class has  its enum defined as `CREATED_TS("CreatedTs", "Created Timestamp", "createdTs")`. I was wondering if I can use equalIgnoreCase() method somewhere to get rid of such type of problem? Any suggestion where should I use?

Comment: @John please put your answer below and accept it. Also, you can clean up the question a bit to make it more useful for others.